# Customizing nginx.conf on elastic beanstalk

Tags: nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I need to customize `keepalive_timeout` settings in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file which defaults to `65` currently on elastic beanstalk ec2 instance.

I followed the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49137188/aws-elastic-beanstalk-504-gateway-timeout) description but when I deploy new code I get nginx error like:

> [emerg] 4551#0: "keepalive_timeout" directive is
>   duplicate in /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf:2

Later I tried to directly update nginx.conf using sed as follow

```
files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf" :
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      client_max_body_size 200M;
      client_header_timeout   300;
      client_body_timeout     300;
      send_timeout            300;
      proxy_connect_timeout   300;
      proxy_read_timeout      300;
      proxy_send_timeout      300;
container_commands:
  01_update_nginx:
    command: "sudo sed -i 's/keepalive_timeout  65;/keepalive_timeout  360;/g' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf"
  02_restart_nginx:
    command: "sudo service nginx reload"
```

Which is not working again (value is not replaced). So I am looking for proper way to update/customize `nginx.conf` file. I tried [something like this](https://gist.github.com/wearhere/19a035423ffe0c940f060ea825926391) 
which gives me an error like:

> Service:AmazonCloudFormation,
>   Message:[/Resources/AWSEBAutoScalingGroup/Metadata/AWS::CloudFormation::Init/prebuild_0_appname/files//opt/elasticbeanstalk/#etc#nginx#custom-nginx.conf]
>   'null' values are not allowed in templates

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go this `sed` route, the command should be this instead:

```
01_update_nginx:
  command: "sudo sed -i 's/keepalive_timeout  65;/keepalive_timeout  360;/g' /tmp/deployment/config/#etc#nginx#nginx.conf"
```

That's the location of the actual `nginx.conf` (and others, like e.g. `00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf`) that Beanstalk uses to replace the default file.

There is no need for the `02_restart_nginx` command, you can remove that one (as of Aug'19).

I tested this on Beanstalk env with Node.js running on 64bit Amazon Linux/4.8.2. Overall though, it looks a bit hacky, you may want to consult with AWS support for the "official" way to customize nginx.conf.